# Can't build project with OpenCV in VS Code, undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to build a project in VC Code with the OpenCV library included.

That's my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the dependency manager vcpkg, and have specified the paths to the libraries and header in tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\user\\gcc\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I", "C:\\dev\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\include",
                "-L", "C:\\dev\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\lib",
                "-lopencv_core4",
                "-lopencv_highgui4"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Users\\user\\gcc\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

But when i run "Debug C/C++ file" in VS Code i get following output:
Starting build...

```
C:\Users\user\gcc\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\vs-test\main.cpp -o 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\vs-test\main.exe -I C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -L C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib -lopencv_core4 -lopencv_highgui4
C:/Users/user/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4jPgv.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/user/Desktop/vs-test/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:/Users/user/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/user/Desktop/vs-test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```